# How can a button's title be changed everytime it is tapped in Xcode 4.3?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xcode4.3, xcode-storyboard

I'm a newbie to iPhone application development. I want to know whether it is possible to create  button with title ABC and when a user clicks on that, the title goes something like XYZ and when the user clicks the button (with title changed to XYZ now) it again changes to the previos one i.e ABC.

I'm using xcode 4.3 with storyboards, any help would be highly appreciated.

An UPDATE: I've impleented the first half of it. That is, when I click ABC, it chnges to XYZ but dont know exactly how to set that XYZ back to ABC on tapping :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a `BOOL` property, say, `buttonIsOn`.

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender
{
    self.buttonIsOn = !self.buttonIsOn;
    NSString * buttonTitle = (self.buttonIsOn ? @"ABC" : @"XYZ");

    [self.button setTitle: buttonTitle forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: I did it and I'm getting this error:
Property 'buttonIsOn' not found on object of type "ViewController"

Comment: The first line of my answer... "Declare a BOOL property, say, buttonIsOn."

Comment: Well, this is pretty simple stuff. Read a book on objective-C and come back when you've got the basics down.

Answer (score 0):

The crude way is to compare the title of the button and change to the other one.

You can also define enum to achieve the same effect (but the code will be more meaningful).

Answer (score -2):

If above answer will not work then ...
Try this :

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed: (UIButton*) sender
{
    self.button=sender;
    self.buttonIsOn = !self.buttonIsOn;
    if (self.buttonIsOn) {
        [self.button setTitle: @"ABC" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [self.button setTitle: @"XYZ" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: I just updated my answer, you should make sure you copy it again.

Comment: NO I need not to copy it again beacause I have changed the code with editing.

Comment: there is no need to do this self.button=sender;

Comment: @AshleyMills I changed a code a little and it works fine now.. Thanks so much.